# show/hide elements breaking style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show or hide input text elements when a checkbox is checked.

I have an `<ul>` list and 4 `<li>`. The 1st and 3rd li are the checkboxes and the 2nd and 4th li are the text input. When a checkbox is checked, jquery shows the input text and if unchecked is hidden. But it's breaking the style.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="price1" value="">
        <label for="price1"><span></span>Se Vende</label>
    </li>
    <li class="price-1" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Precio de Venta"name="price[sale]" />
        <span class="unit unit-2">&euro;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="test">
        <input type="checkbox" id="price2" value="">
        <label for="price2"><span></span>Se Alquila</label>
    </li>
    <li class="price-2" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Precio de Alquiler" name="price[rent]" />
        <span class="unit unit-2">&euro;</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/nazu61p7/

Comment: Why is `ul { max-width: 50% }`?

Comment: Is a responsive design, in my page is 75%.

Comment: Try updating  `ul li` width to 90%

Comment: I'd like the checkbox and the input text horizontal aligned.

Comment: Just remove `display: block` from `.test`.

Comment: is this what you are expecting http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/nazu61p7/1/ ?

Comment: Yes! thanks both, I didn't think that just by remove that and with a simple `<br/>` could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below  snippet of code .

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is('#price1') && $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.price-1').toggle();
        $('ul li:last-child').addClass('test');
    } else if ($(this).is('#price1')) {
        $('.test').removeClass('test');
        $('.price-1').toggle();
    }
    if ($(this).is('#price2')) {
        $('.price-2').toggle();
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
    padding:1em 0 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 9px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
}
.test {
    margin-top:8px;
}
input[type="text"], textarea {
    padding: 0.8em 1em;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    color: #a3a3a3;
    background: white;
    outline: none;
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li style="margin-top: 9px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="price1" value="">
        <label for="price1"><span></span>Se Vende</label>
    </li>
        
    <li class="price-1" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Precio de Venta" name="price[sale]" /> <span class="unit unit-2">&euro;</span>
    </li>
        <br/>
    <li class="test">
        <input type="checkbox" id="price2" value="">
        <label for="price2"><span></span>Se Alquila</label>
    </li>
        
    <li class="price-2" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Precio de Alquiler" name="price[rent]" /> <span class="unit unit-2">&euro;</span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/nazu61p7/1/

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

```
<lu>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />Se Vende
        <div>
            <span>&euro;</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Precio de Venta" name="price[sale]" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With this css:

```
ul li {width: 100%;}
ul li div {width:100%;}
```

Of course you would need to adjust your js a bit.